# Nim: Meaning of exclamation mark before a string constant

Tags: syntax, nim-lang

Reading the macros documentation (http://nim-lang.org/docs/macros.html), I came across this piece of code:

```
nnkIdent(!"echo")
```

I tried to find what the meaning of the exclamation mark is, but could not find anything in the Nim documentation.

So: what is the difference between `"string"`and `!"string"` in Nim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exclamation mark in this context is macro syntax that creates an identifier. [Here](http://nim-lang.org/docs/macros.html#!,string) is the definition:

```
proc `!`(s: string): NimIdent {.magic: "StrToIdent", noSideEffect.}
```

constructs an identifier from the string s